# Parallax: How to avoid blank spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

As you can see I am trying to achieve a parallax effect, albeit with JS not CSS! The trouble I am having as you can see in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/BeOOWX) is the as I scroll there is a blank space on top which keeps increasing? Do you have any ideas for a solution to this? Or rather have the img itself stay fixed and only the banner lines move witth the scroll!

Below my code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var imgPos = scrollTop / 2 + 'px';
  console.log("imgPos", imgPos);
  $('.banner_img_desktop').find('img').css('transform', 'translateY(' + imgPos + ')');
});
```

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: unset !important;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-right: -20px !important;
  .banner_container {
    background-color: #e7e6e4;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font: 10px/10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 5px 0px;
    }
    &:before {
      content: 'Advertisement';
    }
    &:after {
      content: 'Scroll to continue with content';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .banner_content {
      position: relative;
      .banner_img_desktop {
        display: block;
        figure {
          overflow: hidden;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="article one">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam placerat sem at mauris suscipit porta. Cras metus velit, elementum sed pellentesque a, pharetra eu eros. Etiam facilisis placerat euismod. Nam faucibus neque arcu, quis accumsan leo tincidunt varius. In vel diam enim. Sed id ultrices ligula.
    Maecenas at urna arcu. Sed quis nulla sapien. Nam felis mauris, tincidunt at convallis id, tempor molestie libero. Quisque viverra sollicitudin nisl sit amet hendrerit. Etiam sit amet arcu sem. Morbi eu nibh condimentum,
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_container">
      <div class="banner_content">
        <div class="banner_img_desktop">
          <figure>
            <img src="http://www.ucodice.com/kinglinkr/front/img/banner.png" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article two">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam placerat sem at mauris suscipit porta. Cras metus velit, elementum sed pellentesque a, pharetra eu eros. Etiam facilisis placerat euismod. Nam faucibus neque arcu, quis accumsan leo tincidunt varius. In vel diam enim. Sed id ultrices ligula.
    Maecenas at urna arcu. Sed quis nulla sapien. Nam felis mauris, tincidunt
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that expected behaviour? I mean, if the image scroll slower than text, the distance between text and image will naturally increase.. On a side note, for performance reasons it's not a good idea to use $('.banner_img_desktop').find('img') inside your "scroll" function. Try saving that in a variable outside the scroll function.

Comment: I don't see a blank space at the top. What do you mean?

Comment: @JonasGrumann yes that is obvious, that is why I am trying to find to a way to work around it! Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Flink How do you not see it? When you scroll the space between the top banner line and the image keeps increasing creating blank space!